# Regular expression to get last part of a string before a character

Tags: regex, oracle

I have this string on a single column of a single row on an oracle table:

(test-1@gmail.com-**1234567**)

(testAAAcccc@gmail.com-**7654321**)

..

Above it's a single big string.

I need a regular expression to extract all the occurrences (could be 1 or more, 2 in above example) of the 7 numbers above, so the results should be:

**1234567**

**7654321**

I'm trying to to that with various regular expression or oracle functions, I'm not able to get both the occurrences.

Could you please help me?

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need exactly regular expression:

```
select regexp_substr('(test-1@gmail.com-1234567)', '\d{7}' ) from dual
```

To find all occurences:

```
select *
from t,
     lateral(select level occurence_number, regexp_substr(str, '(\d{7})',1,level ) digits7
             from dual
             connect by level<=regexp_count(str, '(\d{7})' )
            );
```

or test query with test data (you can run it as-is to se how it works):

```
with t(str) as (
select '(test-1@gmail.com-1234567)' from dual union all
select '(testAAAcccc@gmail.com-7654321)' from dual union all
select '7654321 1234567 2345678' from dual
)
select *
from t,
     lateral(select level occurence_number, regexp_substr(str, '(\d{7})',1,level ) digits7
             from dual
             connect by level<=regexp_count(str, '(\d{7})' )
            );
```

Comment: Thanks, tomorrow I will try and let you know. Very appreciated! Does it works if the same string has multiple occurrence? Maybe I didn't explain it well, but in a single cell I have the string with many occurrences (and can vary on each row).

Comment: @andQlimax yes, it returns all occurences in case of multiple ones

Comment: is there a way to avoid "lateral" query? Since I have oracle 11.2 (sorry if not specified)

Comment: I also need to add a condition to the main select, let's say where id = 3 (which is a particular row where I have to get all the occcurences of the 7 digits)

Comment: yes, of course, I've posted 2 examples for 11.2 here: https://gist.github.com/xtender/49de5fdcceedc1aa041a15676e83c299

Comment: @andQlimax you can replace 30 with bigger number - it should be bigger than maximum count of expressions in your line. Or you can use (select max(length(str)) from t) instead

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to extract only numbers, if you can do that by:

```
Select SUBSTR(column, INSTR(column,'-', -1) + 1)
from dual;
```

#It is fetching everything from column after dash(-).

If you have paranthesis, if you can replace it with a space and then TRIM:

```
Select TRIM(replace(SUBSTR(column, INSTR(column,'-', -1) + 1),')', ' '))
from dual;
```

Comment: But the first part "test-1@gmail.com-" also could contains numbers. Is there a way to get only the last 7 numbers before each ")" ? Thanks

Comment: SUBSTR('test-1@gmail.com-123456', INSTR('test-1@gmail.com-123456','-', -1) + 1): This is fetching everything after dash..